# Transpose a vector into the third dimension

Tags: matlab

Given a vector `v = [1 2 3 4 5 6]` how do I turn it into:

```
v = 
    v(:,:,1) =  1
    v(:,:,2) =  2
    v(:,:,3) =  3
    v(:,:,4) =  4
    v(:,:,5) =  5
    v(:,:,6) =  6
```

i.e., transpose between the second (row) and third dimension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to use the [permute](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/permute.html) command:

```
permute([1 2 3 4 5 6], [3 1 2])
```

It accepts non-existing dimensions: the second argument specifies swapping the first existing dimension with the third existing dimension (none), which creates a 'singleton' first dimension in the result.

Answer (score 3):

You can also reshape:

`reshape([1 2 3 4 5],1,1,[])`

EDIT (in response to comment): actually, it does:

```
>> reshape([1 2 3 4 5],1,1,[])

ans(:,:,1) =

     1


ans(:,:,2) =

     2


ans(:,:,3) =

     3


ans(:,:,4) =

     4


ans(:,:,5) =

     5
```

Comment: No, reshape does not do that.

Comment: ok, sorry, you're right. It works in this specific case with many singleton dimensions +1